# Android handler read UI/main thread data

Tags: android, process, handler

An activity which has a member arraylist.
This arraylist will be written by activity and read by its/activity handler. 
The data read by the handler sometimes correct and sometimes wrong. This is because the data written by the activity is not synced when handler is reading.

I noticed that the activity and the handler are in different process, even the handler is created by the activity. But the handler is called by another process.

How to make the arraylist data synced/consistent? Thanks.

Code in activity:

```
private Vector<XMPPConnectionInClientCallback> mCallbackList = new Vector<>();

public interface XMPPConnectionInClientCallback {
    void connected(int data);
    void logIned(int data);
    void disconnected(String data);
}

public void addCallback(XMPPConnectionInClientCallback callback) {
    Log.e("connectionclient", "addone");
    mCallbackList.add(callback);
    String strI = String.valueOf(mCallbackList.size());
    Log.e("connectionclient", strI);
}
```

handler in activity:

```
final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //synchronized(mCallbackList) {
        //get data message from Service Process
        int MSGValue = msg.what;
        switch (msg.what) {
            case XmppService.E_CONNECTION_MESSENGER_VALUE:
                try {
                    //callback here
                    String strI = String.valueOf(mCallbackList.size());
                    Log.e("connectionclient size", strI);
                    for (int i = 0; i < mCallbackList.size(); i++) {
                        mCallbackList.get(i).connected(MSGValue);
                    }
                break;
```

I called addCallback() first to add one object to mCallbackList, then after a while the service process will send a message to the handler. The handler will will read object from the mCallbackList. mCallbackList sometime has the object, sometime not.  I notice the handler is running in the service process. While addCallback() is running in the main process.

Comment: Please show some code about the read/write of the arraylist.

Comment: in `handleMessage` call `Log.d` with a `Thread.currentThread`, what do you see? somehing like `Thread[main,5,main]` ?

Comment: I would guess this is a system bug!!! At last, I change to another solution. I tested several cases. All these cases will result in data inconsistent if the handler is in another Process. If in the same process(different thread), there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Vector instead of Arraylist. It is made "thread-safe" by merit of all its methods being synchronized.

Comment: Sorry, I did use vector.